# Run command with PyQt5 and getting the stdout and stderr

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qprocess

I want to run command with PyQt5. And I want to get the stdout and stderr in time order and in real-time.

I separated into UI class and Worker class. There are several UI classes, but for simplicity, I've specified just one.

I've tried to solve this problem, but I can't. I can't connect between the Worker thread and logger function.

**test_ui.py**

```py
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QTextEdit
from worker import Worker


class TestUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button2")
        self.btn3 = QPushButton("Button3")
        self.result = QTextEdit()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.press_btn1)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.press_btn2)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.press_btn3)

        hlayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout1.addWidget(self.btn1)
        hlayout1.addWidget(self.btn2)
        hlayout1.addWidget(self.btn3)

        hlayout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout2.addWidget(self.result)

        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout1)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout2)

        self.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.show()

    def press_btn1(self):
        command1 = "dir"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command1, path)
        self.worker.outSignal.connect(self.logging)

    def press_btn2(self):
        command2 = "cd"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command2, path)
        self.worker.outSignal.connect(self.logging)

    def press_btn3(self):
        command3 = "whoami"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command3, path)
        self.worker.outSignal.connect(self.logging)

    def logging(self, str):
        self.result.append(str.strip())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestUI()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

**worker.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess, pyqtSignal


class Worker:
    outSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    errSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        self.proc = QProcess()

    def run_command(self, cmd, path):
        self.proc.setWorkingDirectory(path)
        self.proc.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
        self.proc.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyStandardOutput)
        self.proc.finished.connect(self.proc.deleteLater)
        self.proc.start(cmd)

    def onReadyStandardOutput(self):
        result = self.proc.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.outSignal.emit(result)

    def onReadyStandardError(self):
        result = self.proc.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.errSignal.emit(result)
```

Update:

Applying [here solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60174168/6622587) and making the following modifications still fails the code:

```py
@pyqtSlot()
def press_btn1(self):
    command1 = "dir"
    path = "./"
    self.worker.run_command(command1, path)

@pyqtSlot()
def press_btn2(self):
    command2 = "cd"
    path = "./"
    self.worker.run_command(command2, path)

@pyqtSlot()
def press_btn3(self):
    command3 = "test.bat"
    path = "./"
    self.worker.run_command(command3, path)

@pyqtSlot(str)
def logging(self, msg):
    msg = msg.strip()
    if msg != "":
        self.result.append(msg)
```

**test.bat**

```
@echo off

echo "Output 1"
timeout /t 1
1>&2 echo "Error 1"
timeout /t 1
echo "Output 2"
timeout /t 1
1>&2 echo "Error 2"
```

---

### Batchfile Issue

This is the result when I run it through the command prompt.

It outputs one line every second in real-time.

```
"Output 1"

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
"Error 1"

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
"Output 2"

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
"Error 2"
```

This is the result of the application.

It outputs whole lines after 3 seconds. And the time order is not right.

```
"Output 1"

Waiting for 1 seconds, press a key to continue ...0

Waiting for 1 seconds, press a key to continue ...0
"Output 2"

Waiting for 1 seconds, press a key to continue ...0
"Error 1"
"Error 2"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following errors:

- The signals only work in the QObjects so it is necessary for Worker to inherit from QObject.
- It is recommended that QProcess not be a member of the class since we say that task 1 is being executed and without finishing you try to execute task 2 so that task 1 will be replaced which is not what you want, instead QProcess can be done be a child of Worker so that your life cycle is not limited to the method where it was created.
- If you want to monitor the stderr and stdio output separately then you should not like processChannelMode to QProcess::MergedChannels since this will join both outputs, on the other hand if the above is eliminated then you must use the readyReadStandardError signal to know when stderr is modified.
- Since QProcess is not a member of the class, it is difficult to obtain the QProcess in onReadyStandardOutput and onReadyStandardError, but for this you must use the sender() method that has the object that emitted the signal.
- The connections between signals and slot should only be made once, in your case you do it in press_btn1, press_btn2 and press_btn3 so you will get 3 times the same information.
- Do not use `str` since it is a built-in function.

Considering the above, the solution is:

**worker.py**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QProcess, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Worker(QObject):
    outSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    errSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run_command(self, cmd, path):
        proc = QProcess(self)
        proc.setWorkingDirectory(path)
        proc.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.onReadyStandardOutput)
        proc.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.onReadyStandardError)
        proc.finished.connect(proc.deleteLater)
        proc.start(cmd)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onReadyStandardOutput(self):
        proc = self.sender()
        result = proc.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()
        self.outSignal.emit(result)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onReadyStandardError(self):
        proc = self.sender()
        result = proc.readAllStandardError().data().decode()
        self.errSignal.emit(result)
```

**test_ui.py**

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QWidget

from worker import Worker


class TestUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.outSignal.connect(self.logging)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button2")
        self.btn3 = QPushButton("Button3")
        self.result = QTextEdit()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.press_btn1)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.press_btn2)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.press_btn3)

        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn1, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn2, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn3, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.result, 1, 0, 1, 3)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def press_btn1(self):
        command1 = "dir"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command1, path)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def press_btn2(self):
        command2 = "cd"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command2, path)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def press_btn3(self):
        command3 = "whoami"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command3, path)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def logging(self, string):
        self.result.append(string.strip())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

**Update:**

QProcess has limitations to execute console commands such as .bat so in this case you can use subprocess.Popen by executing it in another thread and sending the information through signals:

**worker.py**

```py
import subprocess
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    outSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def run_command(self, cmd, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute_command, args=(cmd,), kwargs=kwargs, daemon=True
        ).start()

    def _execute_command(self, cmd, **kwargs):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
        )
        for line in proc.stdout:
            self.outSignal.emit(line.decode())
```

**test_ui.py**

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QWidget

from worker import Worker


class TestUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.outSignal.connect(self.logging)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button1")
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("Button2")
        self.btn3 = QPushButton("Button3")
        self.result = QTextEdit()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.press_btn1)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.press_btn2)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.press_btn3)

        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn1, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn2, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn3, 0, 2)
        lay.addWidget(self.result, 1, 0, 1, 3)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def press_btn1(self):
        command1 = "dir"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command1, cwd=path)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def press_btn2(self):
        command2 = "cd"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command2, cwd=path, shell=True)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def press_btn3(self):
        command3 = "test.bat"
        path = "./"
        self.worker.run_command(command3, cwd=path, shell=True)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def logging(self, string):
        self.result.append(string.strip())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I've already tried using QObject and sender() function before. But I failed. The separation of stdout and stderr does not matter, but it is important that they are output in chronological order.

Comment: Your codes work. But it ran only command3. Command1 and 2 don't work.

Comment: I created the 'test.bat' file for test purposes. But, it also doesn't work. I've updated the code to the question.

Comment: @HoYa Let's go in parts, according to your comment: *Your codes work. But it ran only command3. Command1 and 2 don't work.*, Why do you point out that Command 1 and Command2 don't work?

Comment: @HoYa About .bat I am going to test it recently but I need more details such as what is the path of .bat on your PC with respect to .py. On the other hand, never delete the initial code since you make any solution unusable, instead you must add editions as I have done with your question.

Comment: Because of the command 1 and 2 is sent to run_command but, nothing to print. The onReadyStandardOutput() and onReadyStandardError() function do not print nothing.

Comment: .bat file and .py files are in the same folder. So I've tried to pass the relative path and the absolute path.

Comment: @HoYa 1) 
I had tested it on linux but I'm going to test it on windows recently, the dir command should show the files and directories of the folder but in the case of "cd" I don't expect any output, why do you expect any output of the "cd" command?

Comment: The "cd" command in Windows is the same as the "pwd" command in Linux. I take this command for example of this question. Actually this command is one of the batch file.

Comment: It seems like a command problem. So I've tested several commands."ping", "help", "whoami" commands work well even though the command 1 or 2. But "cd", "dir", "path", "my test.bat" doesn't work. And "ipconfig" command can run with decode error. What are the differences between these commands?

Comment: In contrast, subprocess.popen performs all commands without problems. I don't know why it is.

Comment: @HoYa Why did you delete your previous post? I wanted to adapt it to this case since QProcess has limitations but now I can't access your previous code, can you retrieve your last post?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work except the batch files. The symptoms are added to the question area.

Comment: I thought duplicated questions weren't a waste of resources. It has helpless to other people. So I've removed it.

Comment: @HoYa No, duplicate questions are valid, can you make them visible returned?

Comment: @HoYa  for .bat have you used `self.worker.run_command(command3, cwd=path, shell=True)`? try changing "./" to the full path of the directory to which the .bat belongs

Comment: I've added the symptoms and I've restored the question.

Comment: wow! Thank you so much. It works well. Now, I'm going to try to apply for QThread. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but you can try to have Worker inherit from QObject or QWidget. I'm fairly sure that's needed for signals from a user made class to work.