# Why is log.plaintext responding late in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to see the immediate execution result of stdout after exe's execution on pyqt. I implemented all the actions I want in Python code, and the rest are linked to pyqt's widget. I want to print out the immediate execution result of exe from pyqt. Though everything outputs normally in the cmd window, while only log.insertPlainText part output shows at the last time after all the cmd execution ends.

I am sure this is not a duplicate question. What I want is not a solution from pyqt, but I want to solve it entirely with Python code. I've tried many different things, but the log is still printed all at once at the end of the cmd execution. The reason I used log.insertPlainText instead of print is, because I want to show the output result in pyqt.

What I already tried:

```
cmd = [cmd command]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1) 

for line in iter(p.stdout):
    log.insertPlainText(line)
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

and

```
with Popen([cmd command], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, 
    universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        log.insertPlainText(line)
```

Comment: The problem is buffering, and it's not all under your control.  Have you tried `bufsize=0`?  Is the command you're running under your control?  If so, you can set its output to unbuffered.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, that is not the problem. The problem is that the while True and the for loop block the Qt eventloop, and thus freeze the GUI and the painting. If you want to use Popen then you have to run it in another thread and send the information to "log" through signals. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167832/run-command-with-pyqt5-and-getting-the-stdout-and-stderr/60174168#60174168